# Should I implement different services for each thread or should I put all inside one service?

Tags: java, android, android-service

My question if it is good practice to have multiple services for different types of threads.
For instance, let's say my app offers two type of features: to either host a server on the device or to simply be a client.
So, I would have ServerThread and ClientThread.
I implemented two service ServerService and ClientService and run the relative thread.
By having two services of course I could potentially let the user to start both the server service and client service.
Or would be preferable to basically have all one service and maybe with checkboxes on let the user decide what kind of content (thread) there will be inside that service.

Comment: If your app is targeting Android specifically, add a mention in your title and/or body. That might significantly impact the answers.

Answer (score 0):

First off-  Services and Threads have nothing to do with each other.  Services are not asyncronous in Android.  They're just contexts object that exist without being the foreground app of the phone.  They can create threads to do things, but there is no requirement for them to do so, they do not do so by default, and their lifecycle methods all run on the main thread.  So the question doesn't make sense to begin with.

Secondly-  Android should never be used to run a server.  The entire OS is optimized around not allowing long lived background processes.  Non-foreground services are not allowed to run more than 2 minutes, and foreground processes can still be killed at any time for resources.  So a client-server architecture is generally a bad fit for Android as a whole.